# Sometimes network requests fail without timeout or error

Tags: networking

Sometimes, after browsing some specific websites, like Reddit or Slack, network requests stop working. Investigating using network inspector, I can see that requests are being fired, but there are no responses and neither timeouts.

I already tried to change MTU size in my router settings, as suggested in [Some http requests fail](https://superuser.com/questions/1175418/some-http-post-requests-fail), but the problem continues.

[image: An example here]

Comment: Well, I just found this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1175418/some-http-post-requests-fail
In my router the MTU was set to 0 (default value). I changed to 1024, let see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some http POST requests fail](https://superuser.com/questions/1175418/some-http-post-requests-fail)

Comment: This is the question that I referenced in my first comment. After changing MTU size in the settings, the problem continues. I have already edited the question to include this.